# Improving or replacing a long if statement

Tags: javascript

I have a an if statement that works just fine, however, it has become a bit long and I need help to figure out how I can reduce the lines of code and thereby the readability.

I have a `defaultMonth` and set of `months` and a corresponding `price`. I need to add or reduce the price depending on the `defaultMonth` and `month` selected by the user.

Here are some examples of the output I need (note the interval is the same):

If default month is 60 - set price accordingly:

```
Month    -     Price
60             0.0
48             0.1
36             0.2
24             0.35
12             0.5
```

If default month is 48 - set price accordingly:

```
Month    -     Price
60             -0.1
48             0.0
36             0.1
24             0.25
12             0.4
```

If default month is 36 - set price accordingly:

```
Month    -     Price
60             -0.2
48             -0.1
36             0.0
24             0.15
12             0.3
```

The way I've built it now is with an if statement for each default month and nested ifs for each month.

```
if (defaultMonth === 60) {
    if (month === 60) {
        this.price += 0.0
    }
    if (month === 48) {
        this.price += 0.1
    }
    if (month === 36) {
        this.price += 0.2
    }
    if (month === 24) {
        this.price += 0.35
    }
    if (month === 12) {
        this.price += 0.5
    }
}
if (defaultMonth === 48) {
    if (month === 60) {
        this.price -= 0.1
    }
    if (month === 48) {
        this.price += 0.0
    }
    if (month === 36) {
        this.price += 0.1
    }
    if (month === 24) {
        this.price += 0.25
    }
    if (month === 12) {
        this.price += 0.4
    }
}
if (defaultMonth === 36) {
    if (month === 60) {
        this.price -= 0.2
    }
    if (month === 48) {
        this.price -= 0.1
    }
    if (month === 36) {
        this.price += 0.0
    }
    if (month === 24) {
        this.price += 0.15
    }
    if (month === 12) {
        this.price += 0.3
    }
}
if (defaultMonth === 24) {
    if (month === 60) {
        this.price -= 0.35
    }
    if (month === 48) {
        this.price -= 0.25
    }
    if (month === 36) {
        this.price -= 0.15
    }
    if (month === 24) {
        this.price += 0.0
    }
    if (month === 12) {
        this.price += 0.15
    }
}
if (defaultMonth === 12) {
    if (month === 60) {
        this.price -= 0.5
    }
    if (month === 48) {
        this.price -= 0.4
    }
    if (month === 36) {
        this.price -= 0.3
    }
    if (month === 24) {
        this.price -= 0.15
    }
    if (month === 12) {
        this.price += 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Something I forgot to tell you on SO, but we'd need your whole code (your whole if else if part), not just a piece of code

Comment: Looks like you want to look up both `month` and `defaultMonth` in `0.0,  0.1, 0.2,  0.35, 0.5`, and then return the difference.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were doing this, I'd start by putting the data into a 2 dimensional array. As raw data, it seems to be pretty much this:

| default | 12 | 24 | 36 | 48 | 60 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 36 | -0.2 | -0.1 | 0.0 | 0.15 | 0.3 |
| 48 | -0.1 | 0.0 | 0.1 | 0.25 | 0.4 |
| 60 | 0.0 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.35 | 0.5 |

I don't do a lot of JavaScript, but I think in JavaScript syntax, that works out to something on this general order:

```javascript
var priceTable = { 
    "36": { "12": -0.2, "24": -0.1, "36": 0.0, "48": 0.15, "60": 0.3 }, 
    "48": { "12": -0.1, "24":  0.0, "36": 0.1, "48": 0.25, "60": 0.4 }, 
    "60": { "12":  0.0, "24":  0.1, "36": 0.2, "48": 0.35, "60": 0.5 } 
};

this.price += priceTable[defaultMonth][month];
```